# Sublime Text 3: How can I configure a macro to respond to ALL commands?

Tags: macros, command, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext3

My current dilemma is a difficulty in calling **some** commands. Essentially, I want to create a macro that performs the following operations in sequence:

- `Ctrl + D`
- `Ctrl + C`
- `Ctrl + ;`
- `Ctrl + V`

For those of you who know your keyboard shortcuts, it's evident that this does the following:

- Selects the current word
- Copies it to the clipboard
- Opens the "Goto Anything" search box, and prefixes your query with a `#` sign, denoting you wish to search for a symbol/function
- Pastes the copied word in the search box

I've attempted to create a macro for this by recording each keystroke, but Sublime only seems to want to process the more basic commands (i.e. the copy and the paste). And when I manually attempt to edit the `.sublime-macro file`, it gives me an error on the other two commands, like so:

```
Unknown macro command find_under_expand // <-- Ctrl + D
Unknown macro command show_overlay // <-- Ctrl + ;
```

Is there a way to have Sublime recognize that I want to call these commands? Am I formatting them incorrectly?

Disclaimer: My goal is, effectively, to create a slightly modified version of `goto_definition` (initially bound to `F12`). `goto_definition` will match the *exact* symbol in question, but I need to have it perform a fuzzy search in order to find *similar* symbol definitions.

(I have mirrored this post here: http://www.reddit.com/r/SublimeText/comments/2a56zo/commands_and_macros/)

**Edit:** the current contents of my `.sublime-macro` file are as follows:

```
[
    {
        "args": null,
        "command": "find_under_expand"
    },
    {
        "args": null,
        "command": "copy"
    },
    {
        "args": {"overlay": "goto", "text": "#"},
        "command": "show_overlay"
    },
    {
        "args": null,
        "command": "paste"
    },
    {
        "args": null,
        "command": "left_delete"
    },
    {
        "args": null,
        "command": "left_delete"
    }
]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the current contents of your `.sublime-macro` file.